# Problems with positioning of text within HTML

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to position a paragraph between an image and bullet points. I think I have the right layout within the html but for some reason it is just not displaying correctly. See image below:

[image]

As you can see, the paragraphs appear under everything else but this is not how it is displayed within my html. See below for code:

HTML:

```
<div class="services">
        <div class="serviceHolder" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div class="serviceBox" id="service-plan">
                <div class="serviceIcon"><img src="images/icon-design.jpg" width="129" height="134" alt="design icon"></div>
                <div class="serviceCopy">
                    <h2>Plan</h2>
                    <ul class="serviceBullets">
                        <li><h3>Objectives</h3></li> 
                        <li><h3>Scope</h3></li>
                        <li><h3>Sitemap</h3></li>
                        <li><h3>Wireframes</h3></li>
                    </ul>   
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, porta quis urna tempor vestibulum purus, vulputate condimentum arcu faucibus aliquam enim accumsan, a nulla nullam morbi bibendum eveniet tempus, parturient consequat sociis quis. Suscipit in vitae ornare lobortis sed, porta et minima odio neque maecenas cras, justo in. </p>
                    <p>Justo arcu lacus, quos pellentesque nam sit. Luctus mauris egestas, leo nisl porttitor urna scelerisque ut, mauris sodales sapien donec dolor, arcu a ante vestibulum lorem vitae quam</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.services {
width: 100%; float: left; margin: 30px 0;
}

.services .serviceBox {
width: 898px; padding: 30px; border: 1px solid #43C0C2; background-color: white; float:     left; margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.services .serviceIcon {
float: left; margin: 0 30px 50px 0; width: 129px;
}

.serviceBullets {
float: right; font-weight: 100; width: 150px;
}

.serviceBullets li {
list-style-image: url(../images/bullet.gif); color: #43C0C2; margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.services h2 {
font-size: 40px; margin-bottom: 20px; color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Please specify which browser - http://jsfiddle.net/SsCZT/ seems ok in FF and IE.

Answer (score 0):

You have added `Float:left` to just `right Div` only, You need to update your `left div` also with following code

```
.serviceCopy
{
  float: left;
  width: 721px;
}
```

Also after 2 div you will need to add one more div to clear all floats

```
<div class="serviceIcon"></div>
<div class="serviceCopy"></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

So that your layout won't break.

Comment: Please stop recommending this kind of clear method. It does not work. This is the recommended method. http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have it so that it goes
IMAGE - PLAN AND PARAGRAPH - BULLET POINTS?

Or

IMAGE - Everything else so that the image column is on the left, everything else is on the right?

IF its the former.

Try this:

```
<div class="serviceHolder" style="opacity: 1;">
        <div class="serviceBox" id="service-plan">
            <div class="serviceIcon"><img src="images/icon-design.jpg" width="129" height="134" alt="design icon"></div>
            <div class="serviceCopy">
            <h2>Plan</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, porta quis urna tempor vestibulum purus, vulputate condimentum arcu faucibus aliquam enim accumsan, a nulla nullam morbi bibendum eveniet tempus, parturient consequat sociis quis. Suscipit in vitae ornare lobortis sed, porta et minima odio neque maecenas cras, justo in. </p>
                <p>Justo arcu lacus, quos pellentesque nam sit. Luctus mauris egestas, leo nisl porttitor urna scelerisque ut, mauris sodales sapien donec dolor, arcu a ante vestibulum lorem vitae quam</p>
             </div>
            <div class="serviceBullets">
                <ul>
                    <li><h3>Objectives</h3></li> 
                    <li><h3>Scope</h3></li>
                    <li><h3>Sitemap</h3></li>
                    <li><h3>Wireframes</h3></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So that it has its own div and bullets are separate.

Then float all of them left. And define their widths.
Then add one more div, to clear the floats.